# Java Tree Node selection

Tags: java, jtree

I have a tree and a TreePath to one of its nodes. How do I programatically select this node?
Will setSelectionPath of the JTree object alone work?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. From the Java Documentation

> If any component of the path is hidden
>   (under a collapsed node), and
>   getExpandsSelectedPaths is true it is
>   exposed (made viewable).